# mysql count multi columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a video site and I'm storing hit statistics in a table like this:

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| user_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| video_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| user_agent | varchar(500)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| ip         | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| date_add   | timestamp        | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

I want show stats daily (like `2012-02-14: 5000 web views, 850 iphone views`), like this:

```
+---------------------+---------+---------------+
| date                | web     | iphone        |
+---------------------+---------+---------------+
| 2012-02-09          |    500  | 478           |
| 2012-02-10          |    2377 | 204           |
| 2012-02-12          |    247  | 21            |
| 2012-02-13          |    4879 | 236           |
| 2012-02-14          |    8767 | 101           |
+---------------------+---------+---------------+
```

The iPhone user ID is `2422`, the others are web users.

I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: That's basically a cross-tab, and not easy to do with basic sql. Unless you need to see this kind of output in a raw query result, you're better off doing a regular plain 'group by' query and then doing the transformation in your client.

Comment: your table does not make sense to me.  Please explain the columns.  id, date_id, and ip seem obvious, but the other 3 need some explaination.

Comment: What does your output show, daily number of web users and iphone users. or should it be `Date, Video_id, web_viewers, IPhone_Viewers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE(date_add) AS date, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN user_id = 2422 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Web,
       SUM(CASE WHEN user_id = 2422 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS iPhone
FROM stats
GROUP by DATE(date_add)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, something like this query should do it:

```
SELECT
  DATE(date_add) AS date,
  SUM(user_id != 2422) AS web,
  SUM(user_id = 2422) AS iphone
FROM stats
GROUP BY date
```

You can [try it on SQLize](http://www.sqlize.com/ZQzpNl3pYJ).

By the way, if you want to count "unique visitors" (identified by matching user ID, user-agent string and IP address), you can do it with a subquery:

```
SELECT
  date,
  SUM(user_id != 2422) AS web,
  SUM(user_id = 2422) AS iphone
FROM
  ( SELECT DATE(date_add) AS date, user_id
    FROM stats
    GROUP BY date, user_id, ip, user_agent ) AS foo
GROUP BY date
```

(If you didn't need to split the counts between iPhone and non-iPhone users, you could just use `COUNT(DISTINCT user_id, ip, user_agent)` instead of the subquery.)

Comment: no it will not work. Because this sum user_id im want sum rows.

Comment: In MySQL, the value of a Boolean expression like `user_id = 2422` is 1 if the condition is true and 0 if it is false.  So `SUM(user_id = 2422)` indeed counts the number of rows that have `user_id` equal to `2422`.